# Rendering ReactJS component based on a list of objects

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have the following component:

#### articles_list.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './articles_list.css';

export default class ArticlesList extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      articles: null
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('/articles_all')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({
        articles: json.articles
      });
    });
  }

  render() {

    var teste = () => {
      if (this.state.articles === null) {
        return(<div>No articles</div>)
      } else {
          {this.state.articles.forEach( function(element, index) {
            console.log(element);
            return <div key={index}>{element.title}</div>;
          })}
      }
    }

    return(
      <div className="articles_list">
        <div className="articles_list_title">
          ARTICLES
        </div>
        <div>{teste()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Although the JSON request is working fine and returning an array with five JSON objects, they just don't render!

I am new to ReactJS and read (and watched) lots of tutorials, but it seems I am missing something.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach` returns nothing, you want `Array.prototype.map` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return statement inside a forEach doesn't return the value instead it acts like a `continue` statement, you need  to make use of map

```
var teste = () => {
  if (this.state.articles === null) {
    return(<div>No articles</div>)
  } else {
      {this.state.articles.map( function(element, index) {
        console.log(element);
        return <div key={index}>{element.title}</div>;
      })}
  }
}
```

else if you want to go with forEach you need to modify your code like

```
render() {

    var teste = []

      if (this.state.articles === null) {
        teste.push(<div>No articles</div>)
      } else {
          {this.state.articles.forEach( function(element, index) {
            console.log(element);
            teste.push( <div key={index}>{element.title}</div>);
          })}
      }
    }

    return(
      <div className="articles_list">
        <div className="articles_list_title">
          ARTICLES
        </div>
        <div>{teste}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! But I still get a strange warning: `Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of ArticlesList.` Seems strange because I used `key={index}` in the div.

Comment: In that case try to give a key for `<div>No articles</div>` as well

Comment: Thank you! Everything is fine now!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Comment: I don't want to presume on your kindness, but could you take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382657/strange-warning-in-reactjs-event-handler

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
renderArticles() {
  return _.map(this.state.articles, article => {
    return (
      <li className="list-group-item" key={article.id}>
          {article.title}
      </li>
    );
  });
}


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Articles</h3>
        <ul className="list-group">
          {this.renderArticles()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Map over the list and render it one by one. Here I am using lodash map helper to get this done. Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Comment: There really is no reason to use `_.map` as soon as you have `Array.prototype.map`