# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code

#### articles_list.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './articles_list.css';

export default class ArticlesList extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      articles: null
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('/articles_all')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({
        articles: json.articles
      });
    });
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do something else
  }

  render() {

    var teste = []

    if (this.state.articles === null) {
      teste.push(<div key="1">No articles</div>)
    } else {
      {this.state.articles.forEach( function(element, index) {
        console.log(element);
        teste.push(<div onClick={this.handleClick} className="articles-menu-item" key={index.toString()}>{element.title}</div>);
      })}
    }

    return(
      <div className="articles-list">
        <div className="articles-list-title">
          ARTICLES
        </div>
        <div className="menu-body">{teste}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and it is working fine when I remove the `onClick={this.handleClick}`, but with the event handler there I receive the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined

And nothing is rendered.

For all the examples I've seen, there is nothing wrong with the definition of the event handler. I also tried to define the handler as a arrow function, like:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Do something else
}
```

to see if this could change something, but it was all the same.

Where and how should I define the event handler?

Comment: Use an arrow function inside the forEach. LSS, function declarations are executed in a different context and have a different execution context and thus a different this value, usually window (the global execution context) or undefined in strict mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to bind the `forEach` function and hence the error since, `this` inside forEach function will refer to its own context where `handleClick` is not defined rather than the React Component, Either use `.bind(this)` like

```
 {this.state.articles.forEach( function(element, index) {
    console.log(element);
    teste.push(<div onClick={this.handleClick} className="articles-menu-item" key={index.toString()}>{element.title}</div>);
  }.bind(this))}
```

or `Arrow function`

```
 {this.state.articles.forEach( (element, index) => {
    console.log(element);
    teste.push(<div onClick={this.handleClick} className="articles-menu-item" key={index.toString()}>{element.title}</div>);
  })}
```

Comment: Thanks once more!

Comment: I haven't forgotten. I just didn't know I had to. Completely new to ReactJS and learning by making mistakes.

Comment: In any suc case in future do have a look at whether the binding is done properly

Comment: I'll do that, for sure. Thanks.